# Multiple heatmaps with fixed grid size

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using `seaborn`(v.0.7.1) together with `matplotlib`(1.5.1) and  `pandas` (v.0.18.1) to plot different clusters of data of different sizes as heat maps within a for loop as shown in the following code.

My issue is that since each cluster contains different number of rows, the final figures are of different sizes (i.e. the height and width of each box in the heat map is different across different heat maps)(see figures). Eventually, I would like to have figures of the same size (as explained above).

I have checked some parts of `seaborn`and `matplotlib` documentations as well as `stackoverflow`but since I do not know what the exact keywords are to look for (as evident in the question title itself) I have not been able to find any answer. [**EDIT**: Now I have updated the title based on a suggestion from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Previously the title was read: "Enforcing the same width across multiple plots".]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
clusters = pd.DataFrame([(1,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),(1,'b'), (1,'c'), (1,'d'), (2,'e'), (2,'f')])
clusters.columns = ['c', 'p']
clusters.set_index('c', inplace=True)
g = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((6,4)))
c= pd.DataFrame([(1,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),(2,'b'), (3,'c'), (4,'d'), (5,'e'), (6,'f')])
c.columns = ['i', 'R'] 
for i in range(1,3,1):
     ee = clusters[clusters.index==i].p
     inds = []
     for v in ee:
         inds.append(np.where(c.R.values == v)[0][0])
     f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(13, 15))
     ax = sns.heatmap(g.iloc[inds],  square=True, ax=ax, cbar=True, linewidths=2, linecolor='k', cmap="Reds",  cbar_kws={"shrink": .5},
        vmin = math.floor(g.values.min()), vmax =math.ceil(g.values.max())) 
     null = ax.set_xticklabels(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], fontsize=15)
     null = ax.set_yticklabels(c.R.values[inds][::-1], fontsize=15, rotation=0)
     plt.tight_layout(pad=3)
```

[**EDIT**]: Now I have added some code to create a minimal, functional example as suggested by @Brian. Now I have noticed that the issue might have been caused by the text!

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want your heatmaps to produce figures exactly the same size, you will likely need to get rid of the `square=True` keyword argument in `sns.heatmap`. If the heatmaps are different sizes in terms of rows and columns, you should not expect to get the same size plot with square cells. If that does not resolve your issue, can you create a minimal, functional example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Brian: Removing `square=True` does not fix it! I will try to do that. Tnx!

Comment: Do the plots need to have axis labels and ticklabels? If so, do you need the same size only for the saved image or also for the plot generated on screen?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, they have axis labels but not ticks. But I guess I can modify them later e.g. in `Inkscape` (i.e. we can ignore them I guess). I mainly prefer the same size for the saved image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the following conditions

1. If only the squares in the saved images should have the same size and we don't care about the plot on screen and
2. We can omit the colorbar

the solution is rather straight forward.

One would define the size that one square should have in the final image `squaresize = 50`, find out the number of squares to draw in each dimension (`n`, `m`) and adjust the figure size as

```
figwidth = m*squaresize/float(dpi)
figheight = n*squaresize/float(dpi)
```

where `dpi` denotes the pixels per inch.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dpi=100
squaresize = 50 # pixels

n = 3
m = 4

data = np.random.rand(n,m)
figwidth = m*squaresize/float(dpi)
figheight = n*squaresize/float(dpi)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(figwidth, figheight), dpi=dpi)
f.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)

ax = sns.heatmap(data, square=True, ax=ax, cbar=False)
plt.savefig(__file__+".png", dpi=dpi, bbox_inches="tight")
```

The  `bbox_inches="tight"` makes sure that the labels etc. are still drawn (i.e. the final figure size will be larger than the one calculated here, depending on how much space the labels need).
To apply this example to your case you'd still need to find out how many rows and columns you have in the heatmap depending on the dataframe, but as I don't have it's structure, it's hard to provide a general solution.

Comment: It did work like a charm! Thanks! I am wondering if I could change the title of the question in a way that it is more informative so that others who have the same issue can reach this. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I think the title is ok. People will or will not find it depending on the words in the text they are seaching for. You could go with something like "Multiple heatmaps with fixed grid size" if you really want to change the title.

Comment: How do you set proper fontsizes for title, label  and cell text for varying number of rows and columns?